# Safe dublets with Selenium in .txt.File

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

So, my goal was to write a script, that scrapes users, that used a specific hashtag on Instagram and writes their accounts into a .txt-file and it mostly works!

My problem is, that even though some accounts posted plural pictures, my script does show each name only once. Any idea, how it might be able to kind of count them or get my script to not delete doublets?

I looked for everything but can't find a solution.

**This is my part of writing code:**

```
def generate_initial_information_txt(initial_information):
    initial_information_txt = open("initial_information", "w+")
    for user in initial_information:
        initial_information_txt.write(user + "\n")
```

**This is the part to find the name:**

```
for user in range(30):
            el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]')
            el = el.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            time.sleep(2)
            profile = el.get_attribute('href')
            open_recent_posts_set.add(profile)
            time.sleep(2)
            next_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]')
            next_button.click()
            time.sleep(2)
```

THE URL would be 
https://instagram.com/explore/tags/hansaviertel_ms

So I'm starting to scrape the "Recent" Posts and e.g. the "Hansaforum" posted like 5 of the first 6. If I insert a range of 6 it just throws out a .txt-file with two accounts, not 5 times the "Hansaforum". And I'd like to get the amount of times in any kind of way. –

Thanks :)

Comment: would you mind sharing an URL instance of your target profile

Comment: You mean the URL of the profile I'm about to scrape? That would be https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hansaviertel_ms/ 

So I'm starting to scrape the "Recent" Posts and e.g. the Hansaforum posted like 5 of the first 6. If I insert a range of 6 it just throws out a .txt-file with two accounts, not 5 times the "Hansaforum". And I'd like to get the amount of times in any kind of way.